# Self referencing / parent-child relationship in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first, parent-child, self-reference

I read quite a number of posts of programmers that run into the **Unable to determine a valid ordering for dependent operations. Dependencies may exist due to foreign key constraints, model requirements, or store-generated values** -exception when using a self-referencing relationship in Entity Framework.

I am trying to get a parent-child relationship to work:

```
public class Category {
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public Category Parent { get; set; }
    public List<Category> Children { get; set; }
}
```

This is the configuration I use (Fluent API):

```
Property(c => c.ParentId).IsOptional();
HasMany(c => c.Children).WithOptional(c => c.Parent).HasForeignKey(c => c.ParentId);
//HasOptional(c => c.Parent).WithMany(c => c.Children).HasForeignKey(c => c.ParentId);
```

Both the HasMany() and HasOptional() configurations result in a  "Unable to determine a valid ordering for dependent operations..." exception when I try to save a new category like this:

```
context.Categories.Add(new Category { Name = "test" });
```

I don't understand why EF doesn't insert the Category with a null parentId. The database allows the ParentId foreign key to be null.

Would you be able to tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You must define the `ParentId` in the category class as nullable to use it as the foreign key property for an *optional* relationship:

```
public int? ParentId { get; set; }
```

An `int` property cannot take the value `null` and therefore cannot represent a `NULL` as value in a database column.

Comment: Is there a way to implement this parent-children relationship with attributes (fluent)?

Answer (score 1):

Since someone asked in a comment about doing this with attributes.  You can also utilize data annotations to set this up. Using the same example as above:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

public class Category {
    // You can also add [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]  
    // as an attribute, if this field is to be generated by the database
    [Key] // Define this as the primary key for the table
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(Parent))]  // Link the Parent object to the ParentId Foreign Key
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    public Category Parent { get; set; }

    public List<Category> Children { get; set; }
}
```

This is tested and works in EF 6.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to document and test the annotations approach!