# Self-referencing in code-first POCO classes in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, model-view-controller

I have model:

```
 public class Category
 {
    [Key]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Parent { get; set; }
  }
```

I want to create a database using code first and how I add foreign key for Parent? (Create relation Parent->CategoryId)

Comment: Try [Self referencing / parent-child relationship in Entity Framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9955491/self-referencing-parent-child-relationship-in-entity-framework)

Answer (score 2):

```
    public class Category

 {
    [Key]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? ParentID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ParentID")]
    public virtual List<Category> Subcategories { get; set; }
  }
```