# Set a foreign key for same entity in ef core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I want to build `parent child` entities for the same entity class in `Entity Framework Core`.

So I have a entity like this:

```
public class Definition
{
    public int Id{ get; set; }
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
}
```

I want to set `ParentId` as foreign key that refers another `Definition` Entity as parent entity.
How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Self referencing / parent-child relationship in Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9955491/self-referencing-parent-child-relationship-in-entity-framework)

Answer (score 0):

add a foreign key attribute for parent defination

```
 public class Definition
 {  
    [Key]
    public int Id{ get; set; }

    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ParentId")]
    public virtual Definition ParentDefinition { get; set; }
}
```