# Self referencing / parent-child relationship one-to-zero or one in Entity Framework Core

Tags: entity-framework-core, one-to-one, self-referencing-table

I want to create a referencing / parent-child relationship one-to-zero or one in Entity Framework Core. I mean that my entity could have a parent:

```
public class MyEntity
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public Guid? ParentEntityId { get; set; }
    public MyEntity ParentEntity { get; set; }

    public MyEntity ChildEntity { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to configure it via fluent api:

```
entity.HasOne(x => x.ParentEntity)
    .WithOne(x => x.ChildEntity)
    .HasForeignKey( .... )
```

I do not understand what I do have to write in the last line. I am not either sure my entity is correct.

Can anyone help me please?

**EDIT**: This question does not resolve my problem: [Self referencing / parent-child relationship in Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9955491/self-referencing-parent-child-relationship-in-entity-framework)
My problem is about create the foreign key. This line does not work:

```
.HasForeignKey(x => x.ParentEntityId)
```

`HasForeignKey` expects a string in input.

Comment: @GertArnold no, that not resolve my problem.... I have already seen that question... My problem is in the last line... Last line is not contemplated in a one-to-may relationship

Comment: @GertArnold I do not understand your answer

Comment: My bad, I was mixing up two questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a one-to-one relationship you always have to specify the dependent entity type in the `HasForeignKey` call, i.e. the entity that will contain the foreign key. For a one-to-one relationship between two different classes that makes sense, see the [standard EF example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#one-to-one). For a self-reference it looks obvious that EF should figure out there's no option. Still, you have to specify the type:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>()
    .HasOne(x => x.ParentEntity)
    .WithOne(x => x.ChildEntity)
    .HasForeignKey<MyEntity>(c => c.ParentEntityId);
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer... yes, now it's clearer... just one doubt... perhaps should be: `.HasOne(x => x.ChildEntity).WithOne(x => x.ParentEntity)` instead of `.HasOne(x => x.ParentEntity).WithOne(x => x.ChildEntity)`? This self-reference make me confusion...

Comment: It doesn't make a difference for the data model, or anything actually.